# Use custom name for android module in flutter project

Tags: android, gradle, dart, flutter

I have an existing Android project.
Also, I created a new flutter project. I copied my project to it. Now I have such tree in the file system:

```
my_flutter_project/
    android/
        my_android_module_name/
           src/...
    lib/...
    ios/...
```

When I try to run flutter project I have such error:

```
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?
```

So I should somewhere write `my_android_module_name` instead `app` but where?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that a lot of the flutter stuff is hard-coded to use the :app project and app directory, not just the manifest (See the [gradle reader](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/gradle.dart)). You could open a bug in the flutter repository about it, but I don't imagine it's something that will be changed very quickly as it would be a fairly large change.

If you *really* want to use a different project structure, you could look into using a FlutterView - see [this example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_view). I can't guarantee that it still doesn't have the same requirement of using the `app` folder though.

I'd recommend renaming the module to `app` or creating a fresh project and just copying in the relevant files - it would probably save you time and frustration in the long run if you're committed to using flutter.. They update the android & ios files occasionally, and if you have the same structure it's a lot easier to merge in the changes.